# Bridging CloudMQTT and ThingSpeak

Tags: configuration, mqtt, iot, bridge

I need some help creating bridge from CloudMQTT to Thingspeak. 
Connection URL (mqtt://mqtt.thingspeak.com:1883) is invalid because there is no user info added.

Tried mqtt://zr87:@mqtt.thingspeak.com:1883
with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

In order to connect to the ThingSpeak MQTT broker, you have to supply a username and password. The username is "user" and the password is your ThingSpeak MQTT API Key. The MQTT API Key is listed on your ThingSpeak Account > My Profile page. For more information check out the [ThingSpeak doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/mqtt-basics.html).

Comment: Hi, Tried mqtt://username:password@mqtt.thingspeak.com:1883 with no luck.

Comment: Hi, Also tried `mqtt://username:<MQTT_API_KEY>@mqtt.thingspeak.com:1883` with no luck.
On the cloudmqtt bridging form there are inputs for mqtt url, topic (I fill it with `channels/<my_channel_id>/publish/<channel_writeapi_key>`), local prefix and remote prefix. I leave prefix inputs empty.

Comment: It looks like you have the right address and format for the username and password (as long as you are not including the <>). Do you know how to specify a ClientID?